# Indefinite Integral of $\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos^3{x}\sin^3{x}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How would I go about finding the indefinite integral of $\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos^3{x}\sin^3{x}$? I'm aware that any definite integral of it that is symmetric about zero will be zero because the function is odd, but how would I go about finding its indefinite integral?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think it has an indefinite integral in closed form?  Or do you want an integral as an infinite series or something?

Comment: I found it on a practice test, and while I thought the goal of the problem was to be able to identity the parity, some part of me thought it would have a closed for. But now it has my interest, and any kind of solution would be interesting to see...

Comment: If by absurd the indefinite integral were to have a closed form, it could only be expressed in terms of “incomplete” [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), or $($ [generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) $)$ [hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).